# Laptop keeps crashing after playing some games

Tags: laptop, motherboard

my laptop only just recently kept crashing (the screen freezes and a sound usually heard when having a BSoD can be heard through my headphones) when playing relatively graphically demanding games (my laptop is an Asus TUF Gaming Fx504 with Nvidia GTX 1050). I had to always force shut down it because the laptop just won't respond to anything. At first I thought it was because of the heating or air flow, so I used a fan to fix it, but it still crashes after playing games for about an hour or so. I tried lowering all the graphics to fastest, but still no luck. I decided to then open my laptop casing and it looks as attached. I noticed this black paper-like thing above the RAM. I've opened my case before to install an SSD and an extra RAM so I at least knew that black paper-like thing wasn't in that position before. What should I do?

Comment: Boot with a bootable USB Key and let it run for some time. If it crashes this way as you describe then get it serviced.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1744101/347380